# How to move an image smoothly across Imageview Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have large landscape image, I want to move that image smoothly across the screen without loosing aspect ratio. If you cant understand my question, please have a look at Android Newsstand app in that the cover image on top of the screen moves smoothly across the screen back and forth. how can i achieve that. please have a look at the image attached. The background image needs to move smoothly to the right when it reaches end it should move back to left.. Where should i start ?. Thanks in advance.

**Update: Solution**

[PanningView](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/PanningView) is a library which implements the animated background in the now playing screen of the Play Music app.

[image]

Comment: Maybe copying cropped area to imageview? Because some devices may not support overflowed images or imageviews.

Comment: For Some images PanningView is also Jerky...We should be careful about what image we choose and its dimesions references for whch are easily available in panningView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this library https://github.com/flavioarfaria/KenBurnsView

It is exactly what you are asking i hope :-)

Also do give a look at my this, which is modified ken burns view

https://github.com/HasanFaraaz/BackBurn

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was expecting, can u please tell me is it possible to achieve this without using third party library ??

Comment: i am really sorry no it cant be, but its safe as i have used it on my projects and many other apps use this library(just go down to Used By section)

Comment: hey, @SaiKiran atleast upvote the answer if it helps you in anyway, thanks :-)